# Several books were selected

Tags: probability

> There are 125 different books on the shelf. Several books were
> selected from them, and then put back, each book being selected
> independently of the others with probability p. The next day several
> books were taken from that shelf again according to the same pattern.
> Find the probability that on the second day no books were taken from
> those taken on the first day.

Note that we have 125 books (n=|Ω|=125 ), a few are chosen from them, and in what order is not important by the condition of the problem, and the books are given back.

I use ${n+k-1\choose k}$ to calculate.

Howerever, I am not sure how to solve this at all, really confusing. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Each book has two opportunities to be chosen. The question is asking for the probability that no book is chosen twice.

Comment: Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.  Homework problems are allowed, as long as the protocol is
observed.

Comment: Clarifications requested: "Several books were selected from them, and then put back" : Does this mean that on each day, the books were selected **without replacement**, so that no book could be selected more than once on the same day?  Also, assuming that $n = 125$, is the number of books selected on each day equal to the (unspecified) constant $k$?